# How to use Relay Response URL in Authorize.NET in Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, authorize.net

am currently working on integrating my sample site with Authorize.NET.

So I created a Sandbox account in Authorize.NET.

Using this test account, I am testing DPM and using Relay Response URL.

I have Public IP

I am setting the x_relay_response="TRUE"; x_relay_url="http://182.180.157.5:3000/payments/relay_response";

Controller

```
class PaymentsController < ApplicationController

layout 'authorize_net'
helper :authorize_net
protect_from_forgery :except => :relay_response

# GET
# Displays a payment form.
def payment
   @amount = 125.00
   @sim_transaction = AuthorizeNet::SIM::Transaction.new(AUTHORIZE_NET_CONFIG['api_login_id'], AUTHORIZE_NET_CONFIG['api_transaction_key'], @amount, :relay_response => true, :relay_url => "http://182.180.157.5:3000/payments/relay_response")
end

# POST
# Returns relay response when Authorize.Net POSTs to us.
def relay_response
   puts "In Relay Response"
   puts "Params: #{params}"
   sim_response = AuthorizeNet::SIM::Response.new(params)
   if sim_response.success?(AUTHORIZE_NET_CONFIG['api_login_id'], AUTHORIZE_NET_CONFIG['merchant_hash_value'])
     render :text => sim_response.direct_post_reply("http://182.180.157.5:3000/payments/receipt", :include => true)
  else
      render
  end
end

# GET
# Displays a receipt.
def receipt
    @auth_code = params[:x_auth_code]
end

end
```

Getting This Error

An error occurred while trying to report this transaction to the merchant. An e-mail has been sent to the merchant informing them of the error. The following is the result of the attempt to charge your credit card.

```
  This transaction has been approved.
```

It is advisable for you to contact the merchant to verify that you will receive the product or service.

Any Solution For This

Comment: Relay response requires using a standard port location.

Comment: i try port 80 and 443 but still its not working

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Authorize.Net Direct Post for Magento - An error occurred while trying to report this transaction to the merchant](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55456805/authorize-net-direct-post-for-magento-an-error-occurred-while-trying-to-report)